# Confusion with the DC response of an RC integrator

Tags: active-filter

Below is the beginning section from a tutorial on filters:

> An integrator (Figure 1a) is the simplest filter mathematically, and
>   it forms the building block for most modern integrated filters.
>   Consider what we know intuitively about an integrator. If you apply a
>   DC signal at the input (i.e., zero frequency), the output will
>   describe a linear ramp that grows in amplitude until limited by the
>   power supplies. Ignoring that limitation, the response of an
>   integrator at zero frequency is infinite, which means that it has a
>   pole at zero frequency. (A pole exists at any frequency for which the
>   transfer function's value becomes infinite.

[image]

Can you explain what is meant by "the response of an integrator at zero frequency is infinite, which means that it has a pole at zero frequency."?
What does it mean the response to be infinite? And what does the term pole represent here?

**Edit:**
[image]
In [this](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN733.pdf) document there's a plot for s = jw+sigma. But if s has sigma component, doesn't that mean a damped oscillation? I can understand that for steady state the plot of freq. response is independent of time. But damped input is time dependent and not periodic but yet they can plot it as if it is time independent in that 3D plot for RC passive filter.

3D plot for s=jω+sigma there is still a point on the surface. So surface point at s=jω+sigma is not the same point with s=jω. I can understand s=jω is a sinusoidal input's frequency and has a fixed amplitude over time(time independent) but what is s=jω+sigma? If it is damped oscillation, how can it even be plotted on a surface which is time independent?

hen I look at s = jw axis(when sigma is zero) and for example when jw=628j which is f= 100Hz the vertical axis form that point on that 3D surface will be the response of the filter. This is the amplitude of the steady state response. So we have steady state input output like in Fourier. Now imagine s=jω+sigma = 628j+10. This is not a steady state input, and the vertical axis form that point on that surface will have a single value. But the response should be damped. So what is that value of the damped response on the surface? Is that the max amplitude or the mean value of the damped response?

Comment: The gain of the configuration is: (feedback impedance) / (input impedance). At DC (0Hz), the the capacitor looks like an open circuit, or infinite ohms, so the gain is infinite. A pole is a value of frequency that makes the gain infinite.

Comment: Im wondering in this:http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN733.pdf document theres a plot for s = jw+sigma. But if s has sigma component, doesn't that mean a damped oscillation? I can understand that for steady state the plot of freq. response is independent of time. But damped input is time dependent and not periodic but yet they can plot it as if it is time independent in that 3D plot for RC passive filter.

Comment: The steady state frequency response is obtained when the transient due to \$\sigma\$ has decayed to zero. Then \$s=j\omega\$ gives the freq response. Note the relationship between the Laplace transform and Fourier transform for causal systems.

Comment: I dont get that, please see my edit and the 3D plot for s=jω+sigma there is still a point on the surface. So s=jω+sigma is not the same point with s=jω. I can understand  s=jω is a sinusoidal input's frequency and has a fixed amplitude over time(time independent) but what is   s=jω+sigma?  If it is damped oscillation, how can it even be plotted on a surface which is time independent?

Comment: When I look at s = jw axis(when sigma is zero) and for example when jw=628j which is f= 100Hz the vertical axis form that point on that 3D surface will be the response of the filter. This is the amplitude of the steady state response. So we have steady state input output like in Fourier. Now imagine s=jω+sigma = 628j+10. This is not a steady state input, and the vertical axis form that point on that surface will have a single value. But the response should be damped. So what is that value of the damped response on the surface? Is that the max amplitude or the mean value of the damped response?

Comment: The integrator (op-amp) TF is \$\frac{1}{RCs}\$; the RC network has TF \$\frac{1}{1+RCs}\$. The first has a pole at \$s=0\$, the second has a pole at \$s=-\frac{1}{RC}\$

Comment: If a sine wave is applied to a linear, stable, causal system, the response will be a transient plus a steady state sine wave at the same frequency as the applied. The amplitude and phase will, generally, be different. You can see why this works by considering a simple TF term: \$\large \frac{1}{s+\sigma \pm j\omega}\$. The inverse transform is \$e^{-(\sigma \pm j\omega)t}=e^{-\sigma t}e^{\pm j\omega t}= cos(\omega t) \pm jsin(\omega t)\$, as \$t \rightarrow \infty\$

Comment: Ok but lets focus on the "the response" point on that 3D surface. Imagine you have a damping response for a given inoput in time domain. In s domain when you plot this response what is the response on the surface? Is that the amplitude or a mean value over a time?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'the response point on the 3D surface'. You can't plot a time response in the s-domain. A point in the time domain does not correspond to a point in the Laplace domain in the way I think you mean. It doesn't work that way. For example the LT of \$e^{-at}\$ is \$\frac{1}{s+a}\$; how would you plot this? And why would you want to do it?

Comment: I asked wrong way. Imagine the plot is actually s verus 20*log10(Vout/Vin). What I meant was about Vout/Vin division. Lets say Vin=2*sin(20t+10) and Vout=8*sin(20t+30). In this case the response is 20*log10(8/2) at s=20j+10? Is that the meaning of the plot?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a plot of s versus 20log ... ; if the TF is \$\large \frac{1}{1+RCs}\$, then the output to a sine wave of unit amplitude at 20 rad/sec (i.e. input = 1+j0), will be \$\large \frac{1}{1+j20RC}\$

Comment: Are you just asking what the points not along the axes mean?

Answer (score 1):

The response at D.C. means the value of \$H(0)\$ where \$H(s)\$ is the frequency response. Imagine that you apply a fixed voltage to the integrator input. You will get a ramp as an output of the integrator ignoring the opamp supply rails. This ramp will have various harmonics, if you take its frequency response. Since it goes to infinity its D.C. component, which is the average value, is infinite too. Therefore there is a pole at \$s=0\$. This is a more qualitative way of explaining why \$H(s) = a / s\$.

To see why the ramp \$f(x) = a x\$ has an infinite response at D.C. consider the Laplace transform:
$$H(0) = \int_0^\infty a x \ \mathrm{d}x = \left.\frac{a x^2}{2}\right|_0^\infty = a \infty$$

Comment: Could that be explained in an intuitive way?

Comment: @user134429 I thought it is quite intuitive. What part of the explanation do you have problems with? A pole is simply the value of \$s\$ at which the transfer function goes to infinity.

Comment: 1-) Why do they use s instead if wj? They explain everything for steady state but yet they still use s instead of wj (s has sigma component which is not needed in steady state). I dont get that. 2-) How do they derive the transfer function of this active integrator circuit? 3-) Why DC response goes to infinity and isnt integral of DC is a ramp(why they call ramp response as infinity)? here is the link for the article:http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN733.pdf

Comment: @user134429 The derivation of the opamp transfer function is on page 2 in your document. It is an inverting amplifier. However you have a capacitor instead of resistor. Just substitute \$X_C = 1/sC\$

Comment: Im wondering in that document theres a plot for s = jw+sigma. But if s has sigma component, doesn't that mean a damped oscillation? I can understand that for steady state the plot of freq. response is independent of time. But damped input is time dependent and not periodic but yet they can plot it as if it is time independent in that 3D plot for RC.

Comment: @user134429 yes, you can do that with the Laplace transform. You can see what the response would be in terms of damped sinusoids. It is a complicated subject. You can just substitute \$\sigma = 0\$, if you are just learning about filters.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @user1245 the plot you have is for steady state so it is not a function of time. If you excite  jw+sigma signal you'll get different responses depending on sigma. It is unbounded if sigma is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused about transient and steady state response. The key thing to remember with Linear Time Invariant circuits, is that the system can be completely characterized by its steady state response.

Fourier theory explains how you can generate any transient waveform from the sum of a set of steady state sinewaves. To analyse the response of the circuit to this transient, you simply analyse the steady state response of the circuit to each sinewave component individually, and then sum the result together at the end to get the output transient.

This is why we care only about the steady state response of the the circuit when we analyse it, because once we know this, we can calculate the response of the circuit to any input waveform. Of course in practice there is no such thing as a 'steady state sinewave' because in the real world our sine wave must start at some finite point in time. For many circuits we can approximate the steady state performance by applying a sine wave and waiting for the start transients to die down, but this is not always the case. 'Steady state' is a similar concept to infinity, and you must take care when trying to think intuitively about such things.

Comment: When I look at s = jw axis(when sigma is zero) and for example when jw=628j which is f= 100Hz the vertical axis form that point on that 3D surface will be the response of the filter. This is the amplitude of the steady state response. So we have steady state input output like in Fourier. Now imagine s=jω+sigma = 628j+10. This is not a steady state input, and the vertical axis form that point on that surface will have a single value. But the response should be damped. So what is that value of the damped response on the surface? Is that the max amplitude or the mean value of the damped response?

Comment: just copied this for you

Comment: Sigma does not exist in real life. It is just a way of graphically visualizing the response of the filter. You cannot apply any real signal to the circuit that applies a sigma offset. The idea behind the plot is to show you that the filter response is like slicing the fabric drapped over the filter pole along the real frequency axis. The filter design moves these poles around and this affects the shape of the 'cut' along the real axis that is the filter response. In the integrator example the pole itself is on the real axis. For the RC filter it is not.

Comment: I still cannot find answer to this:  Imagine you have a damping response r(t) for a given input f(t) in time domain. In s domain when you plot this response what is the "value" on the surface(vertical axis)? Is that the amplitude or a mean value of response r(t) over a time?

Comment: I asked wrong way. Imagine the plot is actually s verus 20*log10(Vout/Vin). What I meant was about Vout/Vin division. Lets say Vin=2*sin(20t+10) and Vout=8*sin(20t+30). In this case the response is 20*log10(8/2) at s=20j+10? Is that the meaning of the plot?